# Convert string to time sql or snowflake

Tags: mysql, sql, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

How can I convert 'PT5H19M' to `time` format using SQL? I used in MySQL `STR_TO_DATE('PT5H19M', 'PT%HH%iM')`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is caused by the SQL Mode `NO_ZERO_DATE` being enabled (which it is by default in MySQL 5.7 and above). If you can control the SQL Mode, you can resolve it by unsetting `NO_ZERO_DATE` e.g.

```
SET @@SQL_MODE = REPLACE(@@SQL_MODE, 'NO_ZERO_DATE', '')
SELECT STR_TO_DATE('PT5H19M', 'PT%HH%iM')
```

Output:

```
05:19:00
```

As a workaround if you can't (or don't want to) set the SQL Mode, you could `CONCAT`  a valid date to your string, and then use `TIME` to get the time part of the output e.g.

```
SELECT TIME(STR_TO_DATE(CONCAT('2001-01-01','PT5H19M'), '%Y-%m-%dPT%HH%iM'))
```

Output:

```
05:19:00
```

[Demo on dbfiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=69e6fd62f51861427a4a7944b865904c)

Answer (score 0):

For Snowflake

```
select to_time('PT5H19M', '"PT"HH24"H"MI"M"');
----------------------------------------+
 TO_TIME('PT5H19M', '"PT"HH24"H"MI"M"') |
----------------------------------------+
 05:19:00                               |
----------------------------------------+
```